# What are the possible values of side length of an equilateral triangle such that its area is rational?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, triangles, area

Today my mathematics teacher taught me that, "The area of an equilateral triangle is (√3/4)a² where a is the side length."
First I thought that area of an equilateral triangle can never be rational. Then I tried $a=\sqrt[4]{3}$ then the area was $\frac34 $. Now, I think that   $a=\sqrt[4]{3}$ is the only side length for which the area is rational.
Are there any other values possible?

Comment: What about $a=q\sqrt[4]3$, with $q$ rational and greater than $0$?

Comment: $q=\frac{a^2\sqrt{3}}{4} \Rightarrow a=\frac{2\sqrt{q}}{\sqrt[4]{3}}$, where $q\in \mathbb{Q^+}$. This is equivalent to $\sqrt{r} \sqrt[4]{3}$, where $r\in\mathbb{Q}^+$

Comment: Every positive real number is the area of some equilateral triangle.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Better $a=\sqrt[4]{3r^2}$, where $r\in\mathbb{Q}^+$, then $S=\frac{3r}{4} \in \mathbb{Q}$